# Closing Flash Notice Causes page to redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, cancan, railsapps

I am following the tutorial for devise and cancan integration for rails.
https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan
I notice when a user logs in the flash notice causes the page to reload after it has been closed out. 
I see this in my logs: Redirected to "the root path" Completed 302

here is my routes file

```
App::Application.routes.draw do

resources :videos do
collection do
  post "delete_selected_item"
 end
end

unauthenticated do
  root :to => 'external#index'
  match '/features' => 'external#features'
  match '/pricing' => 'external#pricing'
end

devise_scope :user do
  match '/sign_up' => 'devise/registrations#new'
  match '/sign_in' => 'devise/sessions#new'
end

devise_for :users

authenticated :user do
  root :to => "dashboard#index"
  match 'dashboard/videos' => 'videos#index'
  match 'dashboard/statistics' => 'statistics#index'
  match 'dashboard/analytics' => 'analytics#index'
  resources :users
end

post "zencoder-callback" => "zencoder_callback#create", :as => "zencoder_callback"

end
```

layout code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "BriteVid" %></title>
<meta name="description" content="<%= content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) :  "BriteVid" %>">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="<%= form_authenticity_token %>" />
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/4.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/4.0/video.js"></script>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<link href="<%= image_path("favicon.ico") %>" rel="shortcut icon" />
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= yield(:head) %>
</head>

<body class="<%=params[:controller].parameterize%> <%=params[:action].parameterize%>">

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="navbar-inner">
   <div id="nav_header">
    <%= render 'dashboard/internal_header' %>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
<%= render 'layouts/shared/alerts' %>
  <div id="wrap">
  <div id="main" role="main">
  <%= render 'dashboard/dashnav' %>
     <%= yield %>
     <% if Rails.env.production? %>  <%= render 'layouts/shared/ga' %><% end %> 
   </div>
 </div>
<%= render 'layouts/shared/chat' %>
</body>

</html>
```

Flash Message Code

```
<div class="container">
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
      <div class="alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %> fade in">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="">x</a>
      <center><%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %></center>
    </div>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: View code might be needed to work out why a flash message is causing redirects.

Comment: Try this: `<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>` instead of <a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you shure that you correctly include bootstrap javascript files?

In application.js should be that line:

```
//= require bootstrap
```

Comment: Thanks to you both for answering my question. @Paranoid you pointed me in the correct direction. I had a file called bootstrap.js.coffee which as overwriting the default bootstrap. I deleted the file and everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="">x</a>
```

to this

```
<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">x</a>
```

Now, the page will no longer redirect to root url.

**[edit]**

an empty `href=""` in `<a>` tag reloads the page. so, you can change it to the following:

1. `href="#"` adds an extra entry to the browser history (which is annoying when e.g. back-buttoning).
2. `href="javascript:;"` does not seem to have any problems (other than looking messy and meaningless)

Comment: I try @jnbankston variant, it normally closed flash notice.
Perhaps bootstrap javascript arent included. But, of course, anchor is typical variant in "javascript links"

Comment: Updated my post to explain why having empty `href` attribute is not what you want.